# how to complete the url for SRC tags

Tags: php, image, url

I am trying to get images from a URL using php. I used this link
[Get all images url from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513418/get-all-images-url-from-string?rq=1)

I got it working, but As I tested it, I came across URLs, where

URL is `www.myurl.com/pianos/new/steinway.html?kID=243` which can contain an image 
either `<img src="/images/SteinwayGrand.jpg">`

or `<img src="http://www.myurl.com/images/SteinwayGrand.jpg">`

I am trying to address both these cases, and make the script working, ie display images on my page.
Can anyone suggest some way to cover this kind of tags?

Comment: Got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162191/scrape-full-image-src-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from this post:

[Scrape FULL image src with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162191/scrape-full-image-src-with-php)

with bit of modification to match my application.

Answer (score 0):

using php you could use str_replace to cahnge the ../ to / as in:

```
$new_url = str_replace("../", "/", $url);
```

where str_replace(needle, haystack, input_String);

If not, you caould find a  way to do the same in js.

ADDED INFO
You could use it as in:

$new_url = str_replace("../", "http://www.website.com/", $url);

```
this will replace any ../ into http://www.website.com/
```

Comment: @Louis-Loudog  will this insert the root url to the string? ie, if the url is www.myurl.com/pianos/, and src is "../images/piano.jpg", can I get new_img_url=www.myurl.com/images/piano.jpg?

Comment: @VictorKilo exactly my concern

Comment: TI would simply replace any ../ (replative path) into / (absolute path). the rest of the url would stay the same. This is what i use to 'normalize' my urls.

Comment: you can use it as $new_url = str_replace("../", "http://www.myurl.com/", $url); it will replace any ../ into http://www.myurl.com/

i'll repost in my first answer, cause it's messing up the eaxmple in the comment

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Got it. Thanks, but I guess I need to go a bit further than the normalization alone.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Thanks. It gets a bit more complicated. I updated the question. Can  you check?